# How to set correct absolute url on article with releation to category

Tags: python, django, django-models

Im using [django-categories](http://django-categories.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) to make a custom category model.

I have a article model which relate to the category, but how can I make `get_absolute_url` on the article model like this `/category-path/article-slug`

`/category-path/` could be a path like this: `/top-level-category/sub-level-category/sub-sub-level-category/`

Here is my models.py

```
class Category(CategoryBase):

    order = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ('order', 'name')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Return a path"""
        prefix = reverse('categories_tree_list')
        ancestors = list(self.get_ancestors()) + [self, ]
        return prefix + '/'.join([force_unicode(i.slug) for i in ancestors]) + '/'


class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255)

    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

My urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from apps.news.views import CategoryList


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    #Startpage for app
    url(r'^$', CategoryList.as_view(), name="categories_tree_list")
)


urlpatterns += patterns('apps.news.views',
    url(r'^(?P<path>.+)/$', 'category_detail', name='categories_category'),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if `Category` has a attribute `slug`, if not, you can add it your self.

models.py

```
class Article(models.Model):
    ...

    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        arguments = (self.category.slug, self.slug)
        return reverse('article-detail',arguments)
```

views.py

```
def article_detail(request,category_slug,article_slug):
    article = Article.objects.get(category__slug=category_slug, 
                                  slug=article_slug)
    return render(request, 'article_detail_template.html', 
                  {'article':article})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<category_slug>.+)/(?P<article_slug>.+)$', 
            'app.views.article_detail', name='article-detail'),
)
```

In template use the following to link to a special article

`<a href="{{ article_obj.get_absolute_url }}">{{ article_obj.title }}</a>`

Comment: Yes, that would work great, if the article was in a top-level category. This method does not work when the article is in a sub-level category like `/top-category-slug/sub-category-slug/article-slug/`

Comment: I have a suggestion that your article's slug not end with `/`, then it's easy to judge a url is category or article, and easy to realize what you want